# Application black screen on iOS 13 on launch

Tags: objective-c, swift, swiftify

I recently tried converting an Objective-C project to Swift using Swiftify.
The project has been successfully converted and there are no errors/warning but on running the project the application shows a black screen.

The errors in the console are:

```
Info.plist configuration "Default Configuration" for UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication contained UISceneDelegateClassName key, but could not load class with name "SceneDelegate".
```

and

```
There is no scene delegate set. A scene delegate class must be specified to use the main storyboard file.
```

But as it can be seen from my Project hierarchy there is a SceneDelegate class present.
[image: Project Hierarchy]

Also the contents of my Info.plist file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Also please review the screen recording [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zkIYsVfsLS7BiKTdZz_86vLTwPFmjBDD/view?usp=sharing).
Also here is the link of the [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18oCxpiPYW2aHhvFMpW24lx98l2YmUyM9/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this pair of lines in the Info.plist:

```
<key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
<string>SceneDelegate</string>
```

The issue is that *you* think "SceneDelegate" is the name of the SceneDelegate class, but Objective-C does not think so! You have to write:

```
<key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
```

Comment: @NightFuryLxD Please remove these comments, as they are completely unrelated to this question / answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your window scene like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let controller = YoursatrtController() // your start controller class name
    window?.rootViewController = controller
}
```